# How to provide a custom name to extracted folder from a zip, generated using maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using the maven assembly plugin to package a few directories into a zip file.

The following is the zip.xml.

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <baseDirectory>${project.build.directory}</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/config</directory>
            <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>

    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Following is the plugin configuration in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>create-zip</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
    <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
    <finalName>bootstrap</finalName>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
 </plugin>
```

When I run the assemply, a zip file is created with the name of my maven module, which is as expected. But when I extract this zip file, a folder named 'target' is created which is not very readable. How do i customize the name of this 'target' folder?

Comment: You're setting it to "target" yourself via     `<baseDirectory>${project.build.directory}</baseDirectory>`. Default is `${project.build.finalName}` - see [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html).

Comment: Worked like a charm!..my mistake..will accept it if you can post it as an answer..thx